# How to know if a wifi connection is unlimited?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I mean unlimited in the sense that downloading files makes the connection slower over time till it eventually makes it unusable.

I am connected to a public wifi connection and I want to download some large data. I want to know if doing so will affect the speed of the connection over time.
How to know if a connection is unlimited in this sense ?

Comment: You can see the effects of a slow connection at the time it's slow.  You can diagnose whether certain problems are slowing it down when it happens reliably.  There is no way to measure a provider policy or diagnose in advance whether certain usage will trigger action by the provider.  It's similar to some cable TV providers having a policy of not broadcasting home sports events so that the broadcasts don't hurt actual attendance at the games.  There is nothing you can test at home to see whether a game will be received.

Comment: @fixer1234: So, technically, an unlimited connection only differs from a limited one *only* by the measures the ISP takes when a certain amount of bandwidth usage is exceeded, right ?

Comment: You got it.  It's all at their end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one way to know: contact the connection provider. That's if you are talking about a connection with download quota.

Answer (score 0):

Your question not that clear anyway;
There is no program to know if Internet connection is limited or not, The only way is to call the internet Provider ISP,

when you download big files over public WiFi some providers have QOS policy so when you are using to much bandwidth it will gives you slower speed over time.